# I have recorded and executed jmx script for the application having Okta Integration. how to capture and send RelayState SAMLResponse values in body?

Tags: jmeter, saml, okta

Iam new to Jmeter testing, trying to record and execute jmx script for the application having Okta Integration. how to capture and send  RelayState SAMLResponse values in body? Iam getting error -    **XXXXXX-ext-devtest - Bad Request**

Answer (score 0):

Using suitable [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors). The easiest to use is the [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor), all you need to do is to provide "left" and "right" boundaries and JMeter will save everything in-between and store into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

Then you will need to replace recorded hard-coded values with the JMeter Variables references holding extracted dynamic ones.

Unfortunately we cannot help further without seeing at least partial response, check out [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites) for example solution.